# Using a helper page created on a page X in Y?

Tags: html, razor, helper, webmatrix

I have a page X.cshtml with the following code:

```
@helper CodeTest{
    <h1>Test</h1>
}
```

And on my page Y.cshtml like to use this helper ... how can I call him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the helper from X.cshtml to Z.cshtml, which you should put in App_Code. Then you can call it from anywhere in your application.

```
@Z.CodeTest()
```

Comment: Moved to the App_Code folder, as I call the helper?

Comment: Amended my answer to illustrate how to call it

Comment: Also mentioned here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx